# Computing wedge product of vector fields

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

This is a question of actually linear algebra. Say I have a vector spaces spanned on x3,x4,..., x9 I am trying to find wedge product of two elements of this vector space. My numbers a3, ..., a9 are parameters.  Here is a code:

```
$Assumptions = (Subscript[a, 3] | Subscript[a, 4] | Subscript[a, 5] | 
      Subscript[a, 6] | Subscript[a, 7] | Subscript[a, 8] | Subscript[
      a, 9]) \[Element] 
    Reals && (Subscript[x, 3] | Subscript[x, 4] | Subscript[x, 5] | 
      Subscript[x, 6] | Subscript[x, 7] | Subscript[x, 8] | Subscript[
      x, 9]) \[Element] Vectors[{d}];
Simplify [
 TensorReduce[
  TensorWedge[v3, v4]]]
```

Now my v3 and v4 are

```
2 Subscript[a, 3] Subscript[x, 4] + 
 4 Subscript[a, 4] Subscript[x, 5] + 
 2 Subscript[a, 6] Subscript[x, 7] + 
 4 Subscript[a, 7] Subscript[x, 8] + 6 Subscript[a, 8] Subscript[x, 9]
```

and

```
-2 Subscript[a, 3] Subscript[x, 3] + 
 2 Subscript[a, 5] Subscript[x, 5] - 
 3 Subscript[a, 6] Subscript[x, 6] - Subscript[a, 7] Subscript[x, 7] +
  Subscript[a, 8] Subscript[x, 8] + 3 Subscript[a, 9] Subscript[x, 9]
```

So when I run it, it does not group the resulting wedges as it supposed to be, like there are two x8 wedge x9 instead of just one with a bracket of expression of parameters. Any ideas how I do this?

In fact, I am just computing a wedge product of vector fields (x3..x9 are partials). Is there any better function to use?

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.SE]! Your `v3` and `v4` expressions are identical (I suspect you copied & pasted the same expression twice.)  So when I run your code, the result is `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I have just editted. Also I got the result I was looking for, but with long code... I asked to collect the result by writing explicitly all wedge tensors (21 of them) .

Comment: ```Collect[ TensorReduce [
  TensorWedge[v3, v4]] , {Subscript[x, 3]\[TensorWedge]Subscript[x, 
   4], Subscript[x, 3]\[TensorWedge]Subscript[x, 5], 
  Subscript[x, 3]\[TensorWedge]Subscript[x, 6], 
  Subscript[x, 3]\[TensorWedge]Subscript[x, 7], 
  Subscript[x, 3]\[TensorWedge]Subscript[x, 8], 
  Subscript[x, 3]\[TensorWedge]Subscript[x, 9], 
  Subscript[x, 4]\[TensorWedge]Subscript[x, 5], ......}, Simplify]```

Comment: If you did find a solution, it would be good to post it as an answer below.  You can even accept your own answer—though I'd wait a day or two to do so, since other folks might post alternate answers as well.

Comment: Also, here's a slightly more elegant method of generating the two-form basis:  `Flatten[Table[TensorWedge[Subscript[x, i], Subscript[x, j]], {i, 3, 9}, {j, i + 1, 9}]]`

Comment: Thank you! However, my way is no elegant and in the computations that follows Mathematica does not perform good operations with wedges. I have to collect and specify all wedges